# Need help modyfing a file using Sed

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I am grabbing a  string from style.css and trying use it to replace a string in client_custom.css. The problem is that its only printing the update file on the terminal, but I cant get it to save the updated client_custom.css

Is there anyway I can do this with the following command??

```
sed -n 73p  style.css | cut -c  30-35 | xargs -I :hex: sed 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/'  client_custom.css
```

Comment: Redirect your output to a temporary file and copy it back to client_custom.css. You cannot read from the file and overwrite it at the same time.

Comment: hey. Thanks for the reply. I have tried that and it did't work. It just deletes the tmp.css

`sed -n 73p  style.css | cut -c  29-35 | xargs -I  :hex: sed 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/' client_custom.css > tmp.css |  cp tmp.css client_custom.css`

Comment: Why are you piping it to cp?

Either call 'cp' in the shell prompt or replace the '|' before cp with &&

Comment: Excuse me a little new to unix. I just learned how to pipe commands. Can you please explain  me what is the difference between using  && and pipe?

Comment: I also got it working by doing the following.. 

`sed -n 73p  style.css | cut -c  29-35 | xargs -I  :hex: sed 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/' c_cus.css > client_customm.css | rm c_cus.css`

Comment: Provide the structure of the css files and what you are trying to do. Because the combination of sed and cut can be much simplified awk or something.

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` option of sed will do an inplace editing of the file provided as argument

```
sed -n 73p  style.css | cut -c  30-35 | xargs -I :hex: sed -i 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/'  client_custom.css
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that and it gave me the following error


`sed: 1: "client_custom.css": command c expects \ followed by text`